# Laravel - Unlike the public channels, private channels don't work

Tags: php, laravel, sockets, websocket, pusher

I'm using `Laravel 9.1`, and trying to broadcast on private channels, but unlike the public channels, it doesn't work for some reason!

I have an event like this:

```
class newMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
   use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

   public string $message;

   public function __construct($message = null)
   {
       $this->message = $message;
   }

   public function broadcastOn()
   {
       return new PrivateChannel('notification.' . auth()->user()->username);
   }
}
```

When in `broadcastOn` I return an instance of `Channel`, everything works pretty well, but when I change it to `PrivateChannel`, it doesn't work anymore.

`channels.php`

```
Broadcast::channel('notification.{username}', function ($user, $username) {
    return true;
});
```

> I've tried both `soketi` and `websockets`; In both, I had the same result.

## Configs

In the the `BroadcastServiceProvider.php` file, I've tried all these possibilities:

- `Broadcast::routes();`
- `Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);`

none of them worked.

config/broadcasting.php

```
      'pusher' => [
          'driver' => 'pusher',
          'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
          'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
          'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
          'options' => [
              'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
              'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
              'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 6001),
              'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'http'),
              'useTLS' => false,
              'encrypted' => false,
          ],
      ],
```

## Note

### Authentication Routes Don't Execute

When I try to log something in the authentication scope in the channels.php file before returning a boolean using `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::info($user);` it doesn't log anything!

```
Broadcast::channel('notification.{username}', function ($user, $username) {
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::info($user);
    return true;
});
```

### Socket Servers

When I broadcast on public channels, `websockets` console returns:

```
Connection id 76490676.561659290 sending message {"channel":"notification.admin","event":"App\\Events\\newMessage","data":"{\"message\":\"[2022\\\/04\\\/03 06:26:53]: Pigeon had finished. 'As if it wasn't very civil of you to learn?' 'Well, there was mouth enough for it now, I suppose, by being drowned in my size; and as Alice could not be denied, so she tried.\",\"date\":\"2022-04-03T06:26:53.988364Z\"}"}
```

But **in private** channels, when I try to broadcast something, **it doesn't return or log anything at all;** so it looks for some reason, Laravel even doesn't send the request to the socket server.

Comment: Are you sure that username exists? 
Try to log user data, and see what we have, example:

public function broadcastOn()
{
   Log::info('this must be info about current user', [ auth()->user()]);
   return new PrivateChannel('notification.' . auth()->user()->username);
}

Comment: @VladSalabun it works fine, and it exists, but I realized that I get another error after broadcasting:

`[2022-04-04 10:06:01] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from `users`) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from `users`) at /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:712)`

Comment: Okay, then check please in your .ENV file line: DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 is there corrent address of your database?

Comment: @VladSalabun I solved that problem, but still have the same problem; it just works for public channels.

Comment: @VladSalabun It's weird; when I try to log a message in my channels.php it doesn't get logged!

```Broadcast::channel('notification.{user}', function ($user) {
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::info($user);
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Can you explain how do you solve last problem with connection?
I propose to log data passed in constructor, to make sure that your event is triggered at least. And also you can broadcast to static name private channel to see if messages are logged

Comment: I solved that problem by not using Docker! It seems that in some connections, Laravel doesn't use DB_HOST, and instead, it uses localhost

And, I did what you proposed, and as I said, the user got logged without any problems.

Comment: Does authorization to private channel work? When user connect to channel, you can see some messages, like this: "... authenticated for: private-notification ..." or " ... joined channel: private-notification ..". My guess is based on that Laravel doesn't send any notifications, because there's no one to send them to. Therefore we cant see any messages in console